# Adding items to list view that is data-bound

Tags: c#, uwp

I created a class that has properties of employees. I want my program to be able to add employees to the employees list and then the `ListView` update after.

class file:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string first { get; set; }
    public string last { get; set; }
    public int passcode { get; set; }
}   

public class employeeManager
{
    public static List<Employee> GetEmployee()
    {
        var employees = new List<Employee>();
        employees.Add(new Employee { first = "John", last = "Doe", passcode = 123 });
        return employees;
    }
}
```

page.xaml.cs:

```
Employees.Add(new Employee { first = firstName.Text, last = lastName.Text });
string fullName = Employees[Employees.Count -1].first + " " + Employees[Employees.Count-1].last;
employeeListView.Items.Add(fullName);
```

Page.xaml:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Employee" x:Key="EmployeeListDataTemplate" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <StackPanel Margin="5,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind first}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="25" />
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind last}" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="25" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<ListView Margin="0,33,0,0"  x:Name="employeeListView"  IsItemClickEnabled="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Employees}" Background="#00F2F2F2" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EmployeeListDataTemplate}">
</ListView>
```

The last line in page.xaml.cs: gives me an error:

> system.Exception:"catastrophic failure

Comment: Check ObservableCollection: It is useful for updating items on a List and on the GUI. Also you should implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your class.

Comment: why do you x:Bind the ItemsSource to Employees collection and then add manually a STRING to it as an item? any good reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `employeeListView.Items.Add(fullName);` that you shouldnt use Itemsource to bind a list.

You can try use ObservableCollection instead of List that  `ObservableCollection:INotifyCollectionChanged` can notify when the collection be changed.

If you want to add or remove the item that you can add or remote it in ObservableCollection .

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot!

Comment: @MartinNowak If you think it can help that I want you click the right.

Comment: @MartinNowak If you encounter any difficulties, welcome to ask me .